# Mapping key to make new vertical window in Vim

Tags: vim, keymap

This is really odd. Here's the key mapping from my .vimrc:

`noremap <C-n> :vert new<CR>`

The expected behaviour when I press CTRL-n is that it opens a vertical window but it somehow opens a *horizontal window* on top of the current.

The problem only arises for the mappings. When I try `:vert new` from Vim, I get what I want, a new vertical window.

I have also tried `:vnew` and `:vsplit new`, they all work fine when I manually initiate them. Does not  work with CTRL-n.

Comment: Please share your complete version (`$ vim --version`) and the content of your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: From `$ vim --version`:

`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 12 2013 00:23:33)`

This is my [.vimrc](https://github.com/maverick97/gh.vim/blob/master/.vimrc). Check out line 146.

Comment: I asked for your *complete* version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
noremap  <C-N>    :new<CR>
```

overrides the previous one because `<C-N>` is the same as `<C-n>`.

Choose your mappings more wisely.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :) Then, how do I map keys that are capitalized? I tried something like `<C><S>n` and `<C>N`. Didn't work, how do you map it?

Comment: You don't. `<C-S-n>` would be the canonical representation of `Ctrl+N` (IIRC) but Vim won't make a difference between `Ctrl+N` and `Ctrl+n` anyway. See `:help ctrl-{char}`.